# GROUP BY campo tipo TIME em MySQL

Tags: mysql

Em MySQL tenho uma tabela, um dos campos é do tipo TIME (campo HORA).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao fazer uma consulta assim:

```
SELECT hora 
FROM tabela 
GROUP BY hora
```

Nada é retornado, se eu dou `GROUP BY` em qualquer outro campo, funciona. Faz algum sentido esse comportamento? Se sim, como agrupar os resultados iguais?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25599108/4551469

Comment: caiocafardo, explique como quer que fique o resultado pois eu estou achando que você quer fazer um [ORDER BY](https://paiza.io/projects/5_Vm3XzeIS_Y8cPaNCOyww?language=mysql). <--Link com exemplo

Answer (score 1):

No *MySQL* você precisa "explicitar" como vai ser o agrupamento; acredito que a forma mais prática seja definindo o formato da data no *select* e utilizando no *group by* a do campo ([link referência](https://popsql.com/learn-sql/mysql/how-to-group-by-time-in-mysql)):

```
SELECT date_format(hora,'%Y-%m-%d %H-%i'), count(*)
FROM tabela 
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Valeu! Mas não é um tipo DATETIME, é um tipo TIME apenas, funciona igual? Aqui não deu...

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-time_format-function.php pelo que entendi desse link falando de um método específio pra o tipo `TIME`, deve funcionar sim